# django model gives error on datetime field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi guys I have a model with a datetime field, I tried creating an entry like this

```
Order.objects.create(
    ...
    arrival = datetime(year=t['year'],month=t['month'],day=t['day'],hour=t['hour'],tzinfo=timezone.utc)
}
```

this is the field in the model

```
arrival = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

When I try to save the object I get this error

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback to the question, the full model and the full create call

Comment: Can you show the contents of `t` too?